# Extracting the body from an ActiveMQ message via Camel

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have a route using the Spring DSL as such

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>
    <from uri="activemq:queue:worker?mapJmsMessage=false" />
    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
    <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
      <constant>POST</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <to uri="http://localhost/queue" />
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

The message type is an ActiveMQTextMessage.  I am able to POST the message to the HTTP URL, but what I get seems to be the toString() output:

```
ActiveMQTextMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = false, message....
```

I would like to call the getText() method on the ActiveMQTextMessage instance to populate the route, but I cannot figure out how to get that method called.  I am quite sure I could get this to work in code, but I need to do everything via XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem.  I had mapJmsMessage=false set to handle an exception a few days ago.  I removed it and suddenly it worked fine.

Comment: I have to wait two days before I can